# Accessing element in named vector in R without variable name

Tags: r, vector, element, named

I am trying to access the value of an element in a named character vector in R.  Using the example in
http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/named-vector-members
I tried the following:

```
v = c("Mary", "Sue")
v
[1] "Mary" "Sue"
names(v) = c("First", "Last")
v
 First   Last
"Mary"  "Sue"
v["First"]
 First
"Mary"
```

I would like this to return "Mary" without the name "First" (and that is what is shown in the tutorial above), but when I try it always gives the name along with the value.  I tried to set it to a variable, hoping it would give just the value

```
> teststr = v["First"]
> teststr
 First
"Mary"
>
```

But I still get the variable name (First) along with the value.
I tried the following, but it gives back the same - value along with the element name.

```
>
> v[names(v)=="First"]
 First
"Mary"
>
```

The data I have from my work project also produces the same results. 
Would appreciate help with just getting "Mary" without "First".

Thanks - Pankaj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `unname`

```
> unname(v["First"])
[1] "Mary"
```

Also, you can use `getElement` as an alternative

```
> getElement(v, "First")
[1] "Mary"
```

Comment: Also double brackets: `v[["First"]]`. I don't think a comment above is reason enough to leave it out...